# Securing Web API with Azure-b2c

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am develop a public Web API which will be used by number of external clients. In the past I have used HMAC for authentication and stored usernames and api keys in a database. We have more than 50 potential external client applications which will consume my API. The requirement from client point of view is, the authentication should be easy to implement, should support most of the web client/technologies (asp.net, angular, Node etc).

This time my organisation is interested in using Azure AD B2C. I am not sure if B2C is the right product for this usecase where external client application will use your API.

Does anyone have implemented azure-b2c in a same situation?? any sample app (API+Client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) is about self service user registration, password reset, etc. with easy integration to things like Sign-in w/ Facebook (and many more IDPs (identity providers)).

> Azure AD B2C is a cloud identity management solution for your web and mobile applications. It is a highly available global service that scales to hundreds of millions of identities. Built on an enterprise-grade secure platform, Azure AD B2C keeps your applications, your business, and your customers protected.
>
> With minimal configuration, Azure AD B2C enables your application to authenticate:
>
> Social Accounts (such as Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, and more)
>
> Enterprise Accounts (using open standard protocols, OpenID Connect or SAML)
>
> Local Accounts (email address and password, or username and password)

---

Sounds like [Azure API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/) is what you're looking for.